# Deleting a nonnumerial character from a numerical editText

Tags: java

I am using this code to add a dash('-') in a phone number after the 3rd and 4th number. The code is working just fine. My problem is that when I press backspace, I can't remove the dash. I can even add dots and I can delete them if I press backspace, but with dash it's just impossible.

```
    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        MainActivity.headerName.setText("Verification");
        phoneNumber = (EditText) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.phoneEditText);
        int grup = 1;

        phoneNumber.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            int keyDel;
            String a= phoneNumber.getText().toString();
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            phoneNumber.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

                    if (keyCode == KEYCODE_DEL) {
                        a = a.replace("-" , "");
                        phoneNumber.setText(a);

                        keyDel = 1;
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

            if (keyDel == 0) {
                int len = phoneNumber.getText().length();
                if(len == 3 || len == 7) {
                    phoneNumber.setText(phoneNumber.getText() + "-");
               phoneNumber.setSelection(phoneNumber.getText().length());
                }
            } else {
                if(KeyEvent.isModifierKey(KEYCODE_DEL)) {
                    a = a.replace("-" , "");
                    phoneNumber.getText().toString().replace("-" , "");
                    phoneNumber.setText(a);
                }
                keyDel = 0;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your UI widget is formatting its text. So, after you remove the hyphen, the widget is putting it back.

I suggest you leave the widget alone. Instead, when you need to use the phone number, remove the formatting characters from the value.

```
String.replaceAll("[^\\d]", "")
```

You would use this code when retrieving the value from the widget for some external use. So, you might have a method

```
public String getPhoneNumberUnformatted() {...}
```

That returns only the digits of the widget's value.

Comment: Where should I insert this code. I aldeady tried inside "onKey" function and inside if-else. It's not working.